# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a JSON file from instagram, and I got an error when I make an $http.get :

insta.ctrl :

```
insta.controler 'instaCtrl' ($scope, $http), ->
   $http.get('http://api.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/')
       .success(data), ->
           #done !
       .error(e), ->
           #nah !
```

my apache2's conf

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

Error message on chrome :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load #url_of_intagram_api_here. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It work when I disable the internet security in chrome.
Any ideas?

Comment: duplicate question refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Instagram API doesn't implement [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). However they provide JSONP interface for data retrieving. So what you can do is to use [jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) method:

```
$http.jsonp('http://api.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Note `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` GET parameter you need to send.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OG1sT7A9OM1hWBqCvSmC?p=preview